# Try...catch vs if...else for exceptions - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

What if I want to take user input from the `args[0]` array, but just in case I (the user) forgot to define it, I wanted a prompt to come up - is it better to use an `if` block to determine whether the array item(s) is empty or not, or to catch the exception? So, is this

```
public class Stuff {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String foo;
        if(args.length > 0) {
            foo = args[0];
        }
        else {
            foo = getString("Input? ");
        }
    }
    public static String getString(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt + " ");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        return answer;
    }   
}
```

better or worse than

```
public class Stuff {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String foo;
        try {
            foo = args[0];
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            foo = getString("Input? ");
        }
    }
    public static String getString(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt + " ");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        return answer;
    }   
}
```

Comment: The behavior is not the same. The if example will still throw an ArrayOutOfBoundException because you are trying to access the args[0].
You should use args.length to check if the array is not empty, and then check that the first element of the array is not null.

Comment: *"The if example will still throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` because you are trying to access the `args[0]`."* The OP has changed the array check to `if(args.length > 0) {`. The original question still stands. Which construct is better? `if-else` or `try-catch`? Better in what way, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to test `args.length` rather than reading `args[0]`

But apart from that error, it is better to use `if/else` for the following reasons:

- It makes the code clearer
- It has better performance (although not relevant in this case)
- There is no exceptional condition (it is expected that the args array may be empty in some circumstances e.g. "user error", so the code should be able to handle it). Exception throwing should be reserved for exceptional situations that *shouldn't happen*.

Comment: There is also the issue of [*side effects*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). When a code is "tried", it may make changes to the state of the program or data - changes that should not happen if a certain condition will result in an exception being thrown. Using `if-else` will avoid side effects as it will skip the entire code if the given condition is currently false - resulting in better data integrity.

Answer (score 6):

Your first example will still throw an exception since in the if statement you are still accessing an index which does not exist.

If you want to use an if statement then you should be checking that the length of the array is greater than the index you are trying to access for example:

```
if(args.length > 0)
    foo = args[0];
```

Comment: The original question was modified.. this may no longer be valid.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, if-else is better/faster in this case.

Throwing an exception is used when you are inside a method and you want to say to the caller that something went wrong, and you can't do it with the return value.

But as said Jon Taylor, your if statement won't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need is a single line of code.

```
final String foo = args.length > 0? args[0] : getString("Input? ");
```

Comment: I agree, although a lot of people hate that kind of statement, I personally love them but many don't.  Also it doesn't really answer the question.  Or atleast it doesn't explain why you've changed his if statement.

Comment: @JonTaylor OP is already well-served by yours and other answers. This is a kind of a supplement.

Comment: True :), I do love this kind of statement, to me its very clear and concise.  To be honest I wish more people used them.

Comment: @JonTaylor The most important feature for me is that it is FP-like. Ever since Clojure became my primary language, I use this whenever I can, even in  much more complex combinations (like simulating a lisp `cond` instead of `if`-`else if`-`else if` and similar).

Answer (score 1):

Use if block to check whether array is empty that is easy and faster.

Comment: This is ok but if for example they decide to access element 1 instead of 0, checking it is empy is not sufficient.  Checking that the length is greater than the index is.

Comment: I'm not sure about "faster" in the common case, i.e. when the array element is there all right. I believe there are at least implementations where a try block has no performance impact, and all the work is done in the stack unwinder when an exception actually occurs, so the common case works with one less branching instruction. As performance shouldn't be critical in the above case, it's not a major issue here, but worth considering in general.

Answer (score 1):

Given the correction evidenced by Jon Taylor, I will prefer the version with if.

Not only for the speed gain (that in your example I guess will be not noticeable), but because the code with the if better explains its intents, simplifying future maintenance on the code.